# Search distName in XML

Tags: php, xml

is there any way to get the distName in the following example using PHP?

```
<managedObject class="class" version="version" distName="distName" id="id">
  <defaults name="name"/>
  <p name="a">Some data</p>
  <p name="b">Some data</p>
  <p name="c">Some data</p>
  <p name="d">Some data</p>
  <p name="e">Some data</p>
```

So far I tried to get it using this:

```
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@name, 'c')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo " {$node->parentNode->nodeName}\n";
}
```

But I only get 'managedObject'.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: What library are you using? Is the structure dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`//*[contains(@name, 'c')]"` fetches any element node that has an attribute `name` with the value `c`.

`$node->parentNode->nodeName` would fetch the node name of the parent of a node. The node name on your question is `managedObject`. Here are two possible solutions to get the attribute `distName` of the parent node.

Use DOMElement::getAttribute():

```
echo $node->parentNode->getAttribute('distName'), "\n";
```

Or modify the Xpath expression and fetch the `distName` attribute nodes:

```
$nodes = $finder->evaluate("//*[contains(@name, 'c')]/parent::managedObject/@distName");
foreach ($nodes as $attribute) {
    echo " {$attribute->value}\n";
}
```